# Why does android.support-v4.jar not work?

Tags: android, eclipse

I download the Jar file of "Android-Support-V4" for me to be enable to use the "shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale" method of ActicityCompat Class. But my Problem is that I can't Use the JAr I don't even see the Classes in my eclipse Project. But when I use the Old Jar I can see all classes but the old Jar does'nt have the shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale method.

Please can somebody help me? That is how it looks like and without any error.

[image: New_android-support-v4.jar]

Answer (score 0):

Officialy you can get the library downloading the SDK, find your SDK directory, and its located under:

[sdk-dir]/extras/android/support/v4/android-support-v4.jar

To add a Support Library to your application project:

Open the build.gradle file for your application.
Make sure that the repositories section includes a maven section with the "https://maven.google.com" endpoint. For example:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}
```

Add the support library to the dependencies section. For example, to add the v4 jar library, add the following lines:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile "com.android.support:support-v4-20.0.0.jar"
}
```

As you are using Eclipse:

> To add your JAR file to Eclipse, take the following steps
>
> Create a new folder within Eclipse by right-clicking on your project,
>   and selecting New followed by Folder. The library folder is
>   traditionally called lib (for library) which is what I'll be using
>   throughout this tutorial. Eclipse Android libraries
>
> Find the JAR folder you unzipped earlier. Drag and drop it into the
>   new lib folder, and when prompted select Copy files.
>
> Related Articles Android Development 101: Tools Review of Android SDK
>   Working with NinePatch Stretchable Graphics in Android Protect Your
>   Android Applications from Software Piracy Eclipse Android libraries
>
> Your JAR file will now appear in the lib folder in Eclipse's Package
>   Explorer.
>
> Link Your JAR File to Eclipse Although your JAR file is now displayed
>   in the Package Explorer, you still need to link your JAR file to
>   Eclipse before you can access its functionality.
>
> Start by selecting the Project tab at the top of the screen, and click
>   Properties. Eclipse Android libraries
>
> Select Java Build Path followed by the Libraries
>
> Click the Add JARs… button and select your JAR file from within the
>   lib folder.
>
> Your JAR file will now appear in both the lib and Referenced Libraries
>   folders. You can explore the JAR's resources by clicking Referenced
>   Libraries. You have now successfully added and linked a JAR file to
>   your Android project!

You should see [this](https://www.developer.com/ws/android/development-tools/eclipse-android-tutorial-working-with-libraries.html)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I got the android-v4 exactly from my SDK directory. I am under Eclipse I don't have a build.gradle file. PAny other idea?

Comment: You should consider using Android Studio.

Comment: @evalls  Or Intellij IDEA.

Comment: I will try to see for eclipse

Comment: Ok let me try it.